# How can I separate my divs?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a website that I am working on, It is a WP site using the plugin "Birchschedule" for adding items to a calendar.

The monthly and daily display of the calendar is as it should be but the weekly display is coming out wrong. The names are overlapping and I cannot get the divs to move, and it seems to be the plugin is using some inline css.

here is the link of the page
http://citywestmassage.com.au/roster/

and a screenshot of the error:
[Overlapping Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z8Eg.png)

```
 <div class="fc-event fc-event-vert fc-event-start fc-event-end provider-3996" style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(46, 162, 204); border-color: rgb(46, 162, 204); top: 301px !important; left: 249.69px !important; width: 35.38px !important;">
    <div class="fc-event-inner">
        <div class="fc-event-title">
            <a href="http://citywestmassage.com.au/girls/charlotte">Charlotte</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fc-event-bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the generated html to help potential answerers.

Comment: He already gives and url please read question

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for the past 6 days but no luck, would really appreciate any idea or clue.

I tried messing with the margins, width of div, padding, clear, overflow, display, among a few others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the HTML snippet you provided as well as the markup in Developer Tools.  Yes, the markup has inline style attributes.

Let's look at the styling:

- The `div`s are absolute positioned
- The positioning is forced with `!important`.

This means you are not able to override it in your stylesheet.

The inline style attribute takes precedence over external stylesheets.  And then the `!important` locks in the style, meaning you can't override it in CSS.

### How to Fix

Dive into the plugin and see if you can either configure or override the styling behavior.  Look for opportunities to unregister a script or piece of code that is adding the inline styles.

Resist the temptation to write a separate script that will delay and then overwrite the inline styles.  Why? That's putting duct tape over a root cause problem.  Opt instead to solve the problem.

If you can't find a way to override it, contact the plugin author.  Otherwise, you will need to explore a different solution than that plugin.